# How to show loading spinner between two screens

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, afnetworking, rubymotion

I have an app with two `UITableViewControllers`. Clicking on a cell in the first table view fetches data from the server and then takes the user to the second table view.

When the user clicks, I am loading data from the server and after that showing the second table view. So in between there is a fraction of a second lag since data is loaded from the server.

I would immediately like to show the "loading" spinner when the user clicks a cell in the first table controller and have the "loading" spinner disappear when data has been fetched from the server.

This is what I'm doing currently:

```
Class FirstController < UITableViewController
...
  def tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
    initAFNetworkingClient
    Colors.fetch(AFMotion::Client, self.data[indexPath.row]["id"]) do |data|
      self.navigationController.pushViewController(SecondController.alloc.initWithData(data, self.data[indexPath.row]), animated:true)
    end
  end
...
end
```

Comment: Why not show the second view and have it show a spinner until it gets the data it needs?

Comment: I tried doing that. I showed the second view right away and in viewDidLoad method of the second view I loaded data from the server. However, since data from the server is loaded asynchronously, I get errors because the table view needs the data right away.

Comment: So you coded it wrong (or designed it wrong if the table *must* have data). The table should just have an empty array (zero row count) until the data becomes available.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. coded it wrong. I `numberOfRowsInSection` I was checking if there is any data, if not I was adding a row to suggest "no data...add some more". That whole block needed a check to see if there is any data yet to begin with. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch data asynchronously
2. Start spinner immediately once the fetching started. [MDProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is a good library for this.
3. Stop the spinner once fetching is completed.

Make sure to do the UI changes in main thread.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // main thread tasks here
        }
```